# Can I generate 56kHz signal with MCU running at 1Mhz

Tags: embedded, c, clock, timer

I am new to embedded systems designing. I have to generate a 56kHz signal with a MCU running at 1Mhz. I want high accuracy. If I just use a timer, it gives me 55.55kHz.

Is there any way I can divide the clock frequency to a high value and using that, generate a 56kHz signal?

Comment: You could use a PLL frequency multiplier to create a higher frequency signal to divide down, but that would be hardware that would either need to be present in your system, or added to it.  You might also consider a higher crystal/oscillator frequency, say 8 or 16 MHz.

Comment: You'll have to specify significance. Do you want 56kHz, 56.0kHz or 56.000000kHz? That's a difference. Also, which code did you try with "If I just use a timer"? Last but not least: which MCU are you using? And: do you have 1MIPS or, e.g., 0.25MIPS?

Comment: What is the accuracy on your 1 MHz clock?

Comment: "High accuracy" is no spec at all.  We do engineering here using real numbers.

Comment: @CamilStaps I am using an AtxMega128D4, I haven't written the code but was assuming that if I use the internal timer to generate signals and give it a count of 18, I would get 1Mhz/18 = 55.555kHz. And I need high accuracy, i.e. 55.9999kHz or 56.0kHz if possible.

Comment: What is your clock source?  Use different clock?  4.032 MHz seems to be a standard crystal value.

Comment: The clarifications requested for this question have not yet been made, in several weeks... Also, the question is *too localized*. Please edit the question with the details asked for in the comments above.

Comment: OK, I apologize to the administrator and all other users because of my ignorance of the rules. The first time I sign, so understand my mistake.
Now I will try to answer the scheme set up by Andu aka.
Based on my modest knowledge in the field of electronics, ic CD4017 only divider frequency so that ic 3 X 10 equal to 1000 (10x10x10), which means that the output frequency will be divided by 1000, and therefore this is not a converter of 1Hz. to 1000Hz.
I will analyze the scheme more detail and I'll call if I find something I do not know.

Answer (score 7):

56.00 kHz is 1 MHz / 17.86.  That means a simple integer divider can only hit 1 MHz / 17 = 58.82 kHz or 1 MHz / 18 = 55.56 kHz.  If you can't change the 1 MHz clock (very slow for a normal microcontroller) and can only divide it by a integer, then no, you can't get 56.00 kHz.

There are several options:

Use a different clock frequency.  Find some integer multiple of 56.00 kHz that is otherwise acceptable and use that.  For example 7 MHz / 125 works out exactly.

Do dithering.  If you can accept a little jitter, then you can hit any frequency long term.  In this case you'd have to jitter between 17 and 18 cycles of 1 MHz.  That will be difficult in most micros just because there won't be enough cycles to make the next period value and load it into a hardware counter.  However, this technique could work with any frequency that provides enough cycles.  A higher input frequency also results in less jitter, since the jitter is always one cycle of the input clock.  For example, with a 10 MHz clock you jitter between 178 and 179 cycles.  That is enough cycles to be doable on most micros, although you'd probably still have to code it carefully and pay attention to individual instructions.

Some micros have fancy clock generators built in that effectively do the jitter algorithm in hardware.  Some of the new low end PIC 16F1xxx have such a peripheral, but I don't remember its name off the top of my head.

Use a external oscillator, possibly with PLL multiplier and a divider.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. It was very helpful. I just had one more question. The AtxMega128D4 MCU I'm using has an inbuilt PLL. However, the manual says that it can be used for clock generation. Can the PLL be used for generating the 56kHz signal as well?

Comment: @user: I don't know that micro, but probably the PLL is for generating the clock to the processor.  You probably can't use it to generate a arbitrary external clock, but I'm just guessing.  However, maybe you can find a setting so that it makes a processor clock that is a integer multiple of your desired frequency.

Answer (score 3):

Find highest frequency that divides 1000kHz and 56kHz [GCD(1000kHz, 56kHz) = 8kHz]. Next, use a Phased-locked-loop (PLL) - the cmos 4046 springs to mind.

The PLL has an inbuilt voltage controlled oscillator (VCO) that can be set (with the correct choice of R and C) to roughly generate 56kHz. The 56kHz output can be divided down to 8kHz with a divide by 7 circuit. You can use the MCU for this if it has interrupt driven counter/timers. If not it's a hardware solution.

Now, you need to derive an accurate 8kHz from the 1MHz and quite possibly the MCU will do this too OR you'll need hardware.

The accurate 8KHz is fed into the PLL's phase comparator and the divided down signal from the PLL's VCO is also fed into it. The o/p of the Phase comparator will be a varying DC level superimposed with a lot of AC signals that you'll need to filter with an RC network.

This output feeds the VCO input pin on the PLL and hopefully it should lock the VCO output to 56kHz. Here's a picture I found that shows how 1Hz can be converted to 1kHz: -

[image]

The 3 x 4017's are dividing down the nominal 1kHz output from the VCO in an attempt to match the 1Hz input from the GPS. The PLL's phase comparator output, filter and feedback into the VCO soon gets the VCO "in-lock". The three 4017s are equivalent to the divide by 7 mentioned earlier. The 1Hz signal from the GPS are eqivalent to the accurate 8kHz derived from the 1MHz clock mentioned earlier.

Or, live with 55.55kHz

Answer (score 0):

The AtxMega128D4 will run with an external crystal from 0.4 to 16 MHz according to [its datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-8210-8-and-16-bit-AVR-Microcontrollers-XMEGA-D_Manual.pdf) (page 5). It's not limited to 1 MHz.

Pick a frequency that is an exact multiple of 56 kHz -- for example, a 7 MHz crystal is exactly 125 times 56 kHz.  You should be able to set up your timer using that (or use a 14 MHz crystal and divide by 250).

(I just realized this is an old question, but I think my answer is still useful to have on the site.)